# Is there a way to declare preference for a model or overwrite a model alias in M1?

Tags: magento-1.9, preference

I'm using Magento 1.9.x EE.

I'm looking to overwrite the `Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template::send` function.

I *could* overwrite the core class, but then my changes would be dependent on code that resides outside of the new custom module for my feature and IMO this is bad practice.

I understand Magento 1.x is outdated at this point and doesn't have all the features of Magento 2 but I would like to know if this is possible.

In Magento 2 I could do something like [this](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/build/di-xml-file.html):

```
<!--  File: app/etc/di.xml -->
<config>
    <preference for="Magento\Core\Model\UrlInterface" type="Magento\Core\Model\Url" />
</config>
```

Is this feature possibly to duplicate at all in Magento 1.9.x?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no.

If you are overriding core functionality in m1 and want to add code that is dependent on another extension safely the only thing I can suggest is wrapping code in if blocks

`if(Mage::helper('core')->isModuleEnabled('MyCompany_MyModule')) {`

Comment: I ended up following [this link](https://inchoo.net/magento/overriding-magento-blocks-models-helpers-and-controllers/) and it worked great.

Comment: I misunderstood what you meant. Yes overriding is possible in m1. You can either do it as part of an extension or a local override. You can overide all public methods without too much trouble. Private methods involve more planning. Same as M2. I thought you wanted a preference mechansim which wasn't interrupted if another hard dependant extension  was disabled.

Comment: The `<rewrite>` tag was exactly what I was after. Thanks for your insight though, it's always appreciated.

Comment: Actually I can add something useful to this. Try overriding the same class but different methods in two different extensions. You will get a conflict and only one is used. Its useful to know how to resolve conflicts https://marketplace.magento.com/alekseon-modules-conflict-detector.html